# The order of override and noexcept in the standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the order of override and noexcept required by the standard?

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  // virtual void foo() override {} // Ok
  // virtual void foo() noexcept {} // Ok
  // virtual void foo() noexcept override {} // Ok
  virtual void foo() override noexcept {} // Error
};

int main() {}
```

I'm using gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: You should use GCC 4.8.2; it has significantly improved support of C++11 standard.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I need to use gcc 4.7.2 atm

Comment: The order does matter.

Comment: @Simple Can you quote the standard, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, yes, it is, its just hard to find out, since its a bit scattered. Annex A (Grammar summary) is of some help here. Lets try to find the specific bits:

```
declarator:
    ptr-declarator
    noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type

parameters-and-qualifiers:
    ( parameter-declaration-clause ) attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
    ref-qualifieropt exception-specificationot

exception-specification:
    dynamic-exception-specification
    noexcept-specification

noexcept-specification:
    noexcept ( constant-expression )
    noexcept
```

and then later for override

```
member-declarator:
    declarator virt-specifier-seqopt pure-specifieropt
    declarator brace-or-equal-initializeropt
    identifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt: constant-expression

virt-specifier-seq:
    virt-specifier
    virt-specifier-seq virt-specifier

virt-specifier:
    override
    final
```

So a declarator is the thing that contains the noexcept keyword, but in the member-declarator the virt-specifier comes after the declarator.

Comment: Since the function `foo` in question doesn't have a _trailing-return-type_, determining the form of _declarator_ is a bit more involved than your answer suggests: _declarator -> ptr-declarator -> noptr-declarator -> noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers -> declarator-id attribute-specifier-seq_opt parameters-and-qualifiers_.

Answer (score 9):

In 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] we see:

> D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq opt
>   ref-qualifier opt exception-specification opt attribute-specifier-seq opt

...and in 9.2 [class.mem] we see:

> declarator virt-specifier-seq opt pure-specifier opt

This states that `override` and `final` have to come after `noexcept`.

Answer (score 5):

excerpts from [gram.decl]/A.7, emphasis mine

> ***declarator:**
>
>      **ptr-declarator**
>
>      noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type*
>
> ***ptr-declarator:**
>
>      **noptr-declarator**
>
>      ptr-operator ptr-declarator*
>
> ***noptr-declarator:**
>     declarator-id
>   attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>     noptr-declarator
>   **parameters-and-qualifiers**
>     noptr-declarator [
>   constant-expression<sub>opt</sub> ] attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>
>      ( ptr-declarator )*
>
> ***parameters-and-qualifiers:***
>  `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)`
>   *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>   cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>  ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>
>   **exception-specification**<sub>opt</sub>*

[gram.class]/A.8, emphasis mine

> ***member-declarator:**
>     **declarator virt-specifier-seq**<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>
>
>      declarator brace-or-equal-initializer<sub>opt</sub>
>
>      identifier<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `:`
>   *constant-expression*
>
> ***virt-specifier-seq:**
>     **virt-specifier**
>
>      virt-specifier-seq virt-specifier*
>
> ***virt-specifier:***
>     **`override`**
>    
>   `final`

That is, the *exception-specification* is part of the *declarator*, which comes before the *virt-specifier* in a *member-declarator*.

Comment: Since the function `foo` in question doesn't have a trailing-return-type, you should emphasize *ptr-declarator*, which in the end resolves to a *noptr-declarator*.