# exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version

Tags: c++, exception, c++14

I want to custom an Exception class, here's the code:

```
class TestException : std::exception{
  public:
  const char *what() const override {
    return "TestException";
  }
};
```

I used Clion and the IDE give me a warning on the function `what()`:`exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version`

But if I build the code with gcc, there's no warning came out.
I used c++ 14, gcc 6.5.0

Can anybody help to explain what does the warning mean and can I just ignore it?

Comment: Probably the lack of `noexcept` ?

Comment: As a side note, I recommend inheriting from `std::logic_error` or `std::runtime_error` instead, it is more specific and it also allows you to set the error message right on construction. The base class takes care of `what()`. Lazy formatting is usually a bad idea anyway for (e.g.) the reason given in my comment to P.W's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`what`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) from `std::exception` is a `virtual` function and a `virtual` function in a derived class cannot have a laxer *exception specification* than the function it overrides in the base class.

This is mentioned in the section on "Exception speciﬁcations" in the standard.

> **18.4 Exception speciﬁcations [except.spec]**
>   ...
>   4. If a virtual function has a non-throwing exception speciﬁcation, all declarations, including the deﬁnition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall have a non-throwing exception speciﬁcation, unless the overriding function is deﬁned as deleted.

And the example given (which is somewhat similar to the code in the question) illustrates this as well.

```
struct B 
{ 
  virtual void f() noexcept; 
  virtual void g(); 
  virtual void h() noexcept = delete; 
};
struct D: B 
{ 
  void f(); // ill-formed 
  void g() noexcept; // OK 
  void h() = delete; // OK 
};
```

> The declaration of `D::f` is ill-formed because it has a potentially-throwing exception speciﬁcation, whereas `B::f` has a non-throwing exception speciﬁcation.

The solution is to change your code like:

```
class TestException : std::exception{
  public:
  const char *what() const noexcept override {
    return "TestException";
  }
};
```

See [compilation](https://godbolt.org/z/J75xsE) here.

Comment: What you don't mention is the rather obvious reason why `what()` is `noexcept` – it would be rather annoying to have an exception raised while trying to figure out what some other exception was. This strongly discourages lazy formatting of exception messages, and is also likely why `what()` doesn't return a `std::string` (copying that could throw).

Answer (score 6):

`what` member function of `std::exception` is declared as `noexcept` since C++11. You should therefore make your overridden `what` `noexcept` as well. (Actually, this is what the error message says.)

Note that the `noexcept` keyword must come before the `override` keyword (see, e.g., [The order of override and noexcept in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21577466/580083) for details).

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are facing is related to the fact that you are using C++14, if you would compile with C++17 this becomes an error. Hence I would not recommend ignoring it.

Whats going on?

`std::exception` defines the method `what` as: `virtual const char* what() const noexcept;`. You inherit from this method and you re-implement it without specifying `noexcept`. By result, you are telling that your implementation can throw exceptions, while the base method indicates this should never throw. (And callers will assume so)

This was fixed in C++17, which made `noexcept` part of the type system, and requires you to fix this code:

```
const char *what() const noexcept override
```